# Does Spring4d support inheritance of Entities?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, orm, spring4d

I have two tables in my database representing an inheritance association as you can see below:

```
table person:

row_id  name
1       Fred
2       Jack

table customer:

row_id  credit_limit
1       1000.00
2       2000.00
```

And I mapped these tables structures to the classes below:

```
[Entity]
[Table('person')]
TPerson = class
private
  [Column('row_id', [cpPrimaryKey, cpDontInsert, cpDontUpdate])]
  FId: Integer;

  [Column('name', [])]
  FName: string;
public 
  property Id: Integer read FId;
  property Name: string read FName write FName;
end;

[Entity]
[Table('customer')]
[Inheritence(isJoined)]
TCustomer = class(TPerson)
private
  [Column('row_id', [cpPrimaryKey, cpDontInsert, cpDontUpdate])]
  [JoinColumn('row_id', 'person', 'row_id')]
  FId: Integer;

  [Column('credit_limit')]
  FCreditLimit: Currency;
public
  property CreditLimit: Currency read FCreditLimit write CreditLimit;
end;
```

When I try to get a customer list using the code below I get an error telling me that the table customer does not have a column 'name'

```
function TRepository.GetCustomersByName(const pName: string): IList<TCustomer>;
var
  vCrit: ICriteria<TCustomer>;
  vProp: IProperty;
begin
  vCrit := FSession.CreateCriteria<TCustomer>;

  vProp := TProperty<TCustomer>.Create('name');
  vCrit.Add(vProp.Like(pName, mmStart, False));

  Result := vCrit.ToList;
end;
```

So I was wondering if Spring4d does support to inheritance of entities and I found some attributes that indicates it does, like InheritanceStrategyAttribute and DiscriminatorAttribute. However, I noticed that the InheritanceAttribute isJoined isn't used anywhere and I've tried unsuccessfully to make it works. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No. The attributes and the enum are there but that's all. This feature was never implemented

Comment: thank you @StefanGlienke. Is there an alternative way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [TMS Aurelius](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/aurelius.asp). It fully supports this functionality and is a similar style ORM to spring 4D with many more features. Albeit commercial, not open source and costs money.

Comment: Thank you, Dave. I've seen it. I've chosen the Spring4d just because it's open source.